# How to get Mirrored Vector by Plane on Python

Tags: python, mathematics, vector

How can I get mirrored vector(point) by Plane by using blender python modules?

Plane will be defined as

- plane_normal : Vector
- plane_position : Vector

I need to know function like

```
def get_mirrored_vector(point, plane_position, plane_normal):
    Do Something
    return mirrored_point
```

actually, It sounds more of mathematical problem but I thought there might be existing function on mathutils or other blender modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_plane`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_plane) to project the point onto the plane. This can be done by intersecting the line defined by the point and the point offset by the plane's normal vector with the plane:

`proj = intersect_line_plane(point, point + plane_normal, plane_position, plane_normal)`

Once you have the projected point you can use the vector from the original point to the projection to get the mirrored point.

```
from mathutils.geometry import intersect_line_plane

def get_mirrored_vector(point, plane_position, plane_normal):
    proj = intersect_line_plane(point, point + plane_normal, plane_position, plane_normal)
    mirrored_point = 2 * proj - point
    return mirrored_point
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer with exact code!  I didn't come up with the idea to use line / plane intersection function to use for this purpose. The code worked perfectly, Thank you.